# Java Occurence in LinkedList prints over and over

Tags: java, list

I'm counting the occurrence of a word in a linked list using the Collections.frequency, however because It is in a for loop it reprints the occurrence depending on how many times it finds the word.

For example if i add "test" twice to the list, and print the occurrence it would print

```
test:2
test:2
```

Do I need to move it outside the for loop or something?

```
String word = textField.getText().toLowerCase();
for(String y : wordList) {
   if(y.contains(word)) {
      System.out.println(y + " Occured: " + Collections.frequency(wordList,y) + " times");
    }
}
```

But I want to keep the use of a LinkedList without a set

Comment: Your code is obscure. Why do you use both `String.contains(String)`, which checks for a substring match, and `frequency()`, which scans for an exact match using `String.equals(String)`? If the list contains the strings `{"smart", "fart", "art", "fart"}`, and users enters `"art"`, do you truly want output to be `smart Occured: 1 times`, `fart Occured: 2 times`, `art Occured: 1 times`?

Comment: @Andreas Actually I think equalsIgnoreCase should be used since the word "smart" is the same word as "SMART" when it comes to determining if they are the same word

Comment: @jthort The code does call `toLowerCase()`, so it can be assumed that all the strings in `wordList` are lowercase only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a loop. Just using Collections.frequency using the object (word) would be enough:

```
List<String> wordList = new LinkedList<>();
wordList.add("test");
wordList.add("hello");
wordList.add("test");
wordList.add("world");
wordList.add("test");
wordList.add("hello");
wordList.add("test");
wordList.add("hello");

String word = "test";

System.out.println(word + " Occured: " + Collections.frequency(wordList,word) + " times");
```

Output:

> test Occured: 4 times

Comment: This is only doing a specific word, they want each word that's in the collection

Comment: @jthort that's not what the OP is asking.

Comment: You're right, my mistake

Comment: @Juan Carlos Mendoza Yes that is correct actually. Just a question, I wanted to print the size of the list if the entered string is empty, so `if(word =="") { System.out.println(wordList.size) } but it just prints the `occured: 0`?

Comment: @godlypython never use == when comparing strings in Java. Use the `equals` method instead. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for further information. And the empty string ("") will behave as any other String. So if your list contains the empty string then using the frecuency method will return the number of occurrences of it.

Comment: Thanks, i'll read up on the differences :)

Answer (score 0):

use count variable and print its value outside the for loop.
e.g.

```
int count=0;
 for(String y : wordList) {
   if(y.contains(word)) {
    count++;
}
 System.out.println(y + " Occured: " + count + " times");
}
```

Comment: Since you are comparing words, it would be .equalsignorecase since "Hello" = "hello" what talking about the subject words